# How can I deploy a MySQL database to Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to deploy MYSQL Database to Docker container but I don't know how can I do that. I deployed my Spring Boot project and works fine. I created `Dockerfile` in this project:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ADD ./target/Family-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Family-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "Family-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

But I don't know how can I do with MySQL. I used MySQL Workbench when I created my database.

Comment: https://medium.com/@lvthillo/customize-your-mysql-database-in-docker-723ffd59d8fb

Answer (score 0):

Ideally docker containers should one one service at a time, that means that you would have:

- `app-docker-container`: Container with your Java application
- `db-docker-container`: Container with your database

And then link the database `db-docker-container` to the `app-docker-container`. But this involves too many manual commands that might confuse you more, as an starting point I would suggest you to use [docker-compose (link to an example)](https://medium.com/@itsromiljain/docker-compose-file-to-run-rest-spring-boot-application-container-and-mysql-container-775f15d21416).

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply add MYSQL original image from docker-hub

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ --> check for various in line commands to run

Add `docker-compose.yml` to link both the microservice and database.

https://github.com/thoopalliamar/Spring-Boot-And-Database-Docker -->check this to refer docker-compose.

`network mode` and `hostname` creates a network and links between them.

You need to stop the mysql in localmachine and to get into docker of mysql

`sudo docker mysql -u root -p`

to check the databases